# JNA Keyboard Hook in Windows

Tags: java, windows, jna, keyboard-hook

I have put together a JNA code for installing keyboard hook in Windows (using the JNA examples). The code compiles and everything, and I get the hook installed (I get handle to the hook successfully), also I can uninstall the hook successfully. However, the callback never get called when I press any key on the keyboard. Here is my code (most of it are type definitions got from the JNA examples, go to the "main" directly for my part)

```
import com.sun.jna.IntegerType;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.PointerType;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.FromNativeContext;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIFunctionMapper;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloWorld {
    static Map UNICODE_OPTIONS = new HashMap() {
        {
            put("type-mapper", W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
            put("function-mapper", W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
        }
    };

    public static class LONG_PTR extends IntegerType {
        public LONG_PTR() { this(0); }
        public LONG_PTR(long value) { super(Pointer.SIZE, value); }
    }

    public static class UINT_PTR extends IntegerType {
        public UINT_PTR() { super(Pointer.SIZE); }
        public UINT_PTR(long value) { super(Pointer.SIZE, value); }
        public Pointer toPointer() { return Pointer.createConstant(longValue()); }
    }

    public static class ULONG_PTR extends IntegerType {
        public ULONG_PTR() { this(0); }
        public ULONG_PTR(long value) { super(Pointer.SIZE, value); }
    }

    public static class LRESULT extends LONG_PTR {
        public LRESULT() { this(0); }
        public LRESULT(long value) { super(value); }
    }

    public static class WPARAM extends UINT_PTR {
        public WPARAM() { this(0); }
        public WPARAM(long value) { super(value); }
    }

    public static class LPARAM extends LONG_PTR {
        public LPARAM() { this(0); }
        public LPARAM(long value) { super(value); }
    }

    public static class KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT extends Structure {
        public int vkCode;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
    }

    static HANDLE INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new HANDLE() {
        { super.setPointer(Pointer.createConstant(-1)); }
        public void setPointer(Pointer p) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Immutable reference");
        }
    };

    public static class HANDLE extends PointerType {
        public Object fromNative(Object nativeValue, FromNativeContext context) {
            Object o = super.fromNative(nativeValue, context);
            if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.equals(o))
                return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            return o;
        }
    }

    public static class HHOOK extends HANDLE { }
    public static class HINSTANCE extends HANDLE { }
    public static class HMODULE extends HINSTANCE { }

    public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary  {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32)Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, UNICODE_OPTIONS);

        static final int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

        public static interface HOOKPROC extends StdCallCallback  {
            LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);
        }

        HHOOK SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HOOKPROC lpfn, HMODULE hMod, int dwThreadId);
        LRESULT CallNextHookEx(HHOOK idHook, int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
        LRESULT CallNextHookEx(HHOOK idHook, int nCode, WPARAM wParam, Pointer lParam);

        boolean UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHOOK idHook);
    }

    public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class, UNICODE_OPTIONS);

        HMODULE GetModuleHandle(String name);
    }

    public static HHOOK hHook;
    public static User32.HOOKPROC lpfn;
    public static volatile boolean quit = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
        System.out.println(hMod);

        lpfn = new User32.HOOKPROC() {
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam) {
                System.out.println("here");
                quit = true;
                return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam.getPointer());
            }
        };

        hHook = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, lpfn, hMod, 0);
        System.out.println(hHook);

        if(hHook != null)
            System.out.println("Keyboard hooked, type anything to quit");

        while(!quit) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        if(User32.INSTANCE.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook))
            System.out.println("Unhooked");

    }
}
```

I have done keyboard/mouse hooks several times using both C++ and C# in the past. This my first attempt with Java, and I just don't know whether I imported and mapped the library correctly. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears you need to call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`, which is odd - it is not mentioned in the documentation for [Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985(v=VS.85).aspx). I don't know enough about this part of the API to guess at the reason.

I just used the example classes:

```
import com.sun.jna.examples.win32.*;

public class Callback {
  public static User32.HHOOK hHook;
  public static User32.LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn;
  public static volatile boolean quit = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    W32API.HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
    lpfn = new User32.LowLevelKeyboardProc() {
      public W32API.LRESULT callback(int nCode, W32API.WPARAM wParam,
          User32.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam) {
        System.out.println("here");
        quit = true;
        return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam
            .getPointer());
      }
    };
    hHook = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, lpfn, hMod,
        0);
    if (hHook == null)
      return;
    User32.MSG msg = new User32.MSG();
    while (!quit) {
      User32.INSTANCE.PeekMessage(msg, null, 0, 0, 0);
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    if (User32.INSTANCE.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook))
      System.out.println("Unhooked");
  }
}
```

Comment: Saw another example using GetMessage/DispatchMessage, though never thought it has anything to do with the keyboard hook itself (I never needed them in C++/C#). Really appreciate your help McDowell, I got my sanity again :)

Comment: how to get com.sun.jna.examples.win32? I cannot find it from either jna.jar or platform.jar. Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @Qiang Li - I wrote this code against JNA 3.0.9; the example classes were in `examples.jar`

Answer (score 2):

A minimalist example:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HINSTANCE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HOOKPROC;

public class MainTestKeyHook {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HOOKPROC hookProc = new HOOKPROC_bg();
        HINSTANCE hInst = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

        User32.HHOOK hHook = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInst, 0);
        if (hHook == null)
            return;
        User32.MSG msg = new User32.MSG();
        System.err.println("Please press any key ....");
        while (true) {
            User32.INSTANCE.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0);
        }   
    }
}

class HOOKPROC_bg implements HOOKPROC {

    public HOOKPROC_bg() {
    }

    public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        System.err.println("callback bbbnhkilhjkibh nCode: " + nCode);
        return new LRESULT(0);
    }
}
```