# JNA Win32 examples

Tags: java, eclipse, jna

I'm trying to compile in Eclipse the example code from McDowell here [JNA Keyboard Hook in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078646/jna-keyboard-hook-in-windows)

I downloaded jna.jar from http://java.net/projects/jna/sources/svn/show/trunk/jnalib/dist?rev=1182

Imported into my project, added to the build path, but "com.sun.jna.examples.win32" is empty (white folder package).
Therefore User32.HHOOK is not of known type... or is McDowell combining with temp's example?

Please enlighten me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the platform.jar on the same page as part of the win32 types package. Full class `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK`.