# Java - Getting a key press to register with another window open

Tags: java, mouse, restriction

I recently created an autoclicker, however it had a very large downside. Once activated, there was no way to make it not click certain things, or stop it without literally hitting the stop button on eclipse.

I was trying to figure out a way to:

- Press a key or click a mouse to stop the program(while on another
  window)
- Only click when a certain application has the focus of the screen
  Are any of these possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you leave the natural habitat of the JVM and do some JNI magic, as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206633/find-out-what-application-window-is-in-focus-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179923/how-to-capture-global-key-presses-in-java)

Comment: I was trying to stay in something that could be done in a java program.

Comment: You could use the libraries in those posts. This way you'll write pure Java code, but the libraries do the JNI magic for you.