# Java program for keyboard keys press events

Tags: java, keyboard, listener

Is there any way to write a Java program to find the values of keys pressed without using applet or swings or awt.

Comment: just to understand your question better. Is there a reason or just a general questions?

Comment: @Manikandan - are you looking for a system wide keyboard listener for a non-graphical application? If yes, this question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179923/how-to-capture-global-key-presses-in-java

Comment: Why not AWT?  What can you use?  SWT?  Android APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `java.awt.event.KeyListener`

Your code should look something like this:

```
f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key pressed code=" + e.getKeyCode() + ", char=" + e.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this uses `awt` and not using it is one of the question's requirements