# Java program controlled by Console?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I want to know if its possible to control my game with arrow keys.
It is basic version of "2048" game as a console output. 
My idea:

```
if(arrowKeyRight is pressed)
{
  moveNumbersToRight
}
```

The same for the other arrow keys.

Is it possible for my program to read the arrow keys as an output?

Comment: and your question would be?

Comment: What is your question here ?

Comment: I want to know if its possible for my programm to read arrow keys as an output in console. if yes, how. many thanks!

Comment: Please, take a look at this question and replies
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255549/how-can-i-get-the-keyboard-scan-code-in-java

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if you can use a KeyListener or similar construct from a *standard* Java console, then the answer is no since the standard Java console requires the user to press the enter key before keypresses are accepted. So for this to work, the user would have to press an arrow key and then press enter, but how do you respond if the user presses several different arrow keys and then enter? You can do this with 3rd party console libraries, such as [Java Curses](http://javacurses.sourceforge.net/) or with Java GUI programs.