# How to get hex value (hexcode) of the pressed key (e.g. control key) in Java

Tags: java, keyboard

I am trying to get hexcodes of all the keys on the keyboard. For e.g. one that works for me is '0x2C' for printscreen. Can someone help me write a code snippet to get the hexcodes to map the keys as for printscreen key.

```
arg0.getVirtualKeyCode() == 0x2C  //This is true when I press printscreen key
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17255549/18157

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link for key board virtual codes

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx