# Detect Ctrl and Alt keys at a Java console

Tags: java, jline

I'm currently using JLine (http://jline.sourceforge.net/) to read characters from the console in Java one at a time.

```
Terminal terminal = TerminalFactory.getFlavor(TerminalFactory.Flavor.WINDOWS);
terminal.init();
terminal.setEchoEnabled(false);

int i;
InputStream in = terminal.wrapInIfNeeded(System.in);

i = in.read();
```

How can I detect if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys are pressed when I called `in.read();`? I can't figure out from either the javadocs or any other source how to read if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get keyboard scan codes which can be done using a native library.  See: [How can I get the keyboard scan code in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255549/how-can-i-get-the-keyboard-scan-code-in-java)  Specifically: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook