# How to detect modifier keys in a tty?

Tags: java, linux, keyboard, tty

First and foremost: I don't have and don't want a display protocol. I am just using Linux's `tty` (specifically in [Tiny Core Linux](http://www.tinycorelinux.net/) but I don't believe this is of significant importance)

To test if what I am trying to achieve is even possible, I looked through various libraries in all kinds of languages, most of them need a display protocol or didn't recognize modifier keys.
After a lot of searching I found the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module in python (which worked after building `kbd` from source).
It is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, every key press is recognized, even from modifier keys (the exception is the `fn` key of course).

The only problem is that it is the wrong programming language. Is there any comparable module for Java that works without GUI? I am also open to hints on how one would implement such thing if there isn't any library for it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want the functionality of using key scan codes. But, unless you use a GUI, Java offers no support for that. You might get some help from answers to [How can I get the keyboard scan code in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255549/how-can-i-get-the-keyboard-scan-code-in-java) or similar questions.