# JNA Using LParam in a Low Level Mouse Proc Callback

Tags: java, jna

I am attempting to monitor mouse events with Low Level Mouse Hook in Java using the  JNA (or Java Native Access) to check for the `LLMHF_INJECTED` flag. I cant figure out for how to cast the lparam pointer to a `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` like I would in c++. This is what my current callback function looks like.

```
LowLevelMouseProc LLMP = new LowLevelMouseProc() {
    public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {


        if (nCode >= 0){

        }

        Pointer ptr = lParam.toPointer();
        long peer = Pointer.nativeValue(ptr); 
        return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam,new LPARAM(peer));
    }
};
```

I also have the hook struct outlined in its own class as shown below:

```
public class MSLLHOOKSTRUCT extends Structure{

public static class ByReference extends MSLLHOOKSTRUCT implements Structure.ByReference {};

    public POINT pt;
    public DWORD mouseData;
    public DWORD flags;
    public DWORD time;
    public ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I just need to know how to map the pointer to the `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`.

Comment: You could just add a mapping for `CallNextHookEx` which takes `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` as a final argument.  JNA will take care of the rest.

Comment: @technomage can you give me an example, because everything I try doesn't seem to work. I'm quit new to JNA in general.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078646/jna-keyboard-hook-in-windows)