# keylistener in java not working

Tags: java

I want my java program to be running in the background by default, but use a keylistener to call my changewallpaper class. The changewallpaper class definently works, but the keylistener does not call the method. The keyevent will be changed later it's currently just for testing.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class listener implements KeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        int key = arg0.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                changewallpaper.main();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        int key = arg0.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                changewallpaper.main();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        int key = arg0.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                changewallpaper.main();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `something.add(my_listener)` anywhere in your code?

Comment: nope, didn't see anything like that in the example from oracle.. i dont think. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/KeyEventDemoProject/src/events/KeyEventDemo.java

Comment: @jerhynsoen Look again. `addKeyListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A KeyListener does not listen to all keyboard events indiscriminately - it only listens to events on a particular Component, when that Component has keyboard focus. You have to attach the listener to something with an [addKeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener%28java.awt.event.KeyListener%29) method or similar.

See the Java [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) tutorial

Comment: so i can't just tell it to listen for a key anytime or anywhere? like if I am using another program for example?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not - you can listen within your application though (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714349/global-keylogger-in-java). The only way round this is to use native code hooked into Java through JNI.