# Keylogging in Java for Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, keyboard, awtrobot, keylogger

I need a program/library to record all keystrokes (Java preferred). I disassembled a normal keyboard to build a custom interface for certain programs. An interface which provides a physical interface for certain shortcuts. As I need to remap keystrokes depending on the application which is running, a keystroke-logging library is needed.

For example I want to do things like this:

- Key <kbd>a</kbd> -> Winamp is running -> <kbd>b</kbd> (Next track)
- Key <kbd>a</kbd> -> Chrome is running -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (New Tab)
  ...

So I do not want to log the passwords of my friends/family...

Cross-platform would be great, but if this is not possible Mac OSX is preferred.

Comment: Not possible in pure Java - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714349/global-keylogger-in-java, for example

Comment: Other languages are welcome, too!